# Ubuntu server cannot access the Internet: appears DNS related

Tags: ubuntu, dns, ping, resolv.conf

This is a Drupal website running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Linode. The server is just a website. It is not a DNS server or anything else.

Here are my issues. It seems they are all related to DNS issues. (I've been troubleshooting this with Linode for a couple days and I also [got help here regarding iptables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/iptables-rules-too-restrictive-drupal-webserver-cannot-access-repositories-ntp). Now I can focus on the issues in this question.)

1. Our Mollom spam protection is not working on the Drupal site because the server cannot reach the external service. (more details below)
2. Drupal reports, "Your system or network configuration does not allow Drupal to access web pages, resulting in reduced functionality." (more details below - our Drupal config did not change)
3. the server cannot ping the Internet

   ```
   ping google.com  
   ping: unknown host google.com
   ```
4. Other network services fail. For example:

   ```
   $ sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
   Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3) 1 Jun 16:42:34 ntpdate[7420]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)  
   apt-get update
   Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                        
     Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
   Err http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                 
     Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
   ```
5. The server is running very poorly. Could errors like the following one be related to inability to access the Internet?

   ```
   Out of memory: Kill process 2300 (mysqld) score 129 or sacrifice child
   Killed process 2300 (mysqld) total-vm:354780kB, anon-rss:53180kB, file-rss:0kB
   Out of memory: Kill process 5937 (mysqld) score 60 or sacrifice child
   Killed process 5937 (mysqld) total-vm:344040kB, anon-rss:78988kB, file-rss:0kB
   ```

Here are the Drupal errors in more detail. Drupal configuration was not changed before these errors started (afaik).

1. > HTTP request status Fails Your system or network configuration does
   >   not allow Drupal to access web pages, resulting in reduced
   >   functionality. This could be due to your webserver configuration or
   >   PHP settings, and should be resolved in order to download information
   >   about available updates, fetch aggregator feeds, sign in via OpenID,
   >   or use other network-dependent services. If you are certain that
   >   Drupal can access web pages but you are still seeing this message, you
   >   may add $conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE; to the bottom of
   >   your settings.php file.
2. ```
   Mollom API keys Service error
   The Mollom API keys could not be verified. Please try again later.
   This issue prevents members from registering for our site or posting comments.
   ```

Here is the information I think may be relevant:

```
root@example1:/etc# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 789.456.123.6
nameserver 789.456.123.7

root@example1:/etc# cat /etc/hosts
#127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1       example1.local          example1
192.168.150.8   example1                example1
123.456.789.55  example1.example.com    example1        www.example.com

root@example1:/etc# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis


root@example1:/etc# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         123.456.789.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
123.456.789.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 eth0


root@example1:/etc# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# This line ensures that the interface will be brought up during boot.
auto eth0 eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
 address 123.456.789.55
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 123.456.789.1
 dns-nameservers 789.456.123.6 789.456.123.7

# eth0:0 - Private IPs have no gateway (they are not publicly routable) so all you need to specify is the address and netmask.
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 192.168.150.8
 netmask 255.255.128.0

root@example1:/etc# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ether 76:49:bf:95:98:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.150.8/17 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 123.456.789.55/24 brd 123.456.789.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 1000:aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaa/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591730sec preferred_lft 604530sec
    inet6 fe80::aaaa:aaa:fffff:ffff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: teql0: <NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 100
    link/void 
5: tunl0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
6: gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
7: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
8: ip6tnl0: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
9: ip6gre0: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/[823] 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00


root@example1:/etc# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:123.456.789.55  Bcast:123.456.789.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 1000:aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaa/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::aaaa:aaa:fffff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:54198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7588512 (7.5 MB)  TX bytes:67678447 (67.6 MB)
          Interrupt:77 

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.150.8  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.128.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:77 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13579 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:852371 (852.3 KB)  TX bytes:852371 (852.3 KB)

root@example1:/etc#
```

Here's more info:

```
# ping -n 789.456.123.7
PING 789.456.123.7 (789.456.123.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 789.456.123.7: icmp_req=1 ttl=63 time=2.46 ms
64 bytes from 789.456.123.7: icmp_req=2 ttl=63 time=1.80 ms
^C
--- 789.456.123.7 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.802/2.132/2.462/0.330 ms

ping -n 173.194.37.100 (NOTE: this is google.com)
PING 173.194.37.100 (173.194.37.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.37.100: icmp_req=1 ttl=55 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.37.100: icmp_req=2 ttl=55 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.37.100: icmp_req=3 ttl=55 time=14.5 ms
^C
--- 173.194.37.100 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.188/14.325/14.513/0.168 ms
```

And more info:

```
root@example1:/etc# dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@example1:/etc# dig www.google.com @8.8.8.8
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> www.google.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

root@example1:/etc# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=51 time=1.05 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=51 time=1.08 ms
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.058/1.073/1.089/0.036 ms

root@example1:/etc# traceroute google.com
google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cannot handle "host" cmdline arg `google.com' on position 1 (argc 1)

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Although I cannot reach the Ubuntu repos to install software the usual way, I downloaded nmap locally and then copied the deb package to the server using SCP.

Here are the results of `nmap -sS -sU -p 53`:

```
Host is up (0.00085s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
53/udp open  domain
```

Comment: The files that control DNS resolution are `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts`. Could you post them, please?

Comment: And by the way, how can you ping `789.456.123.7` which isn't a correct IP address (just curious)?

Comment: @lgeorget I added `/etc/hosts` to the question. `/etc/resolv.conf` was already there. I also added more test results such as dig. (I did a search/replace on the actual nameserver IPs before posting which is why you see `789.456.123.7` used. I was taught to alway obfuscate IP addresses, but I can post the real nameservers if needed.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem may not be your host but `789.456.123.6` and `789.456.123.7` which supposedly are DNS servers but doesn't behave cooperatively. You can verify this by replacing the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` by `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220` which are OpenDNS' resolvers.

Comment: The current dns nameservers belong to Linode.com. However, maybe the problem is how I'm setting those? I'm using /etc/network/interfaces to set them.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem as `/etc/resolv.conf` is correctly formatted.

Comment: Could you give the result of the following command `nmap -sS -sU -p 53 789.456.123.7`?

Comment: After changing to OpenDNS' resolvers I ran `sudo ifdown eth0` and `sudo ifup eth0`. I inspected /etc/resolv.conf
and the changes are reflected there. Then I ran my tests again. I am still unable to ping google.com or run `apt-get update` etc. What should I try next?

Comment: Unfortunately, the program 'nmap' is currently not installed. I cannot reach the repos to install it. :-(

Comment: It looks like your server is unable to make a DNS request. Is there a firewall on your server or which could get in the way?

Comment: Actually, the link gets me to this current question but... I believe you. Well, then, I'm afraid I can't help you more, I don't see what could get in the way. Do you know other people having trouble with their server on Linode?

Comment: I was able to add the nmap output you requested to the question.

Comment: I do not believe the firewall is the problem now. See this question I asked:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/iptables-rules-too-restrictive-drupal-webserver-cannot-access-repositories-ntp

Comment: I fixed the link to my other question.

Comment: to test if the firewall was the problem, I used `iptables -F OUTPUT`. That should be sufficient, right?

Comment: Well, no, it's not sufficient. You're allowing your host to issue the request but the answer might still be blocked.

Comment: @Christopher: this is a remote server without ufw. If I run `udo iptables -F` I will be locked out. I listed the iptables rules here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/iptables-rules-too-restrictive-drupal-webserver-cannot-access-repositories-ntp

Comment: @Christopher don't the results of `nmap -sS -sU -p 53` show that it is not blocked?

Comment: I appreciate if you would look at my related question and see if you think the iptables rules prevent DNS nameserver responses from being received. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77910/iptables-rules-too-restrictive-drupal-webserver-cannot-access-repositories-ntp

Comment: I am not using selinux

Comment: @Christopher you were right! I added this iptables rule and ping is now working `-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53: -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` Is that rule secure or did I open it up too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shut off the firewall to detect a firewall problem, or add a rule to accept UDP on port 53. Could also allow TCP on port 53. Try to keep a leash on configuration changes and keep a backup of all important configuration files.